# adding two defined dataframes in spark scala dataframe for spark API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a processed dataframe which I want to append to the original dataframe. But it seems to be hard in Spark Scala. Could anyone get over this.?

Things I tried:

Used sql.sparkcontext to add dataframes but didnt work.
tried using withcolumn but didnt work. I tried everything written on Stack Overflow.

tried Union and UnionAll (But it only returns first dataframe)

My next ideas:

Converting a dataframe to column and add (No resource found)

Here are my printSchemas

[print schema 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGNxR.png)

[print Schema 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4l6A.png)

Both DataFrames have the same printSchema which is "org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame"

Union method is not working even though, they both have same number of columns and belong to same Schema

[Failed Case of Union](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggts7.png)

Comment: Can you post the output of printSchema call on both data frames?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @sramalingam24. I have added them above.

Comment: There are two way to merge data frames in spark, one is Join which will merge columns from the two, it requires that the 2 df have common column (s) to merge on and the other is Union which will merge the rows of the two, it requires that the 2 df have same schema. I don't see either here

Comment: union didnt work for me though they both have same number of columns and schema. I am trying Join now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your code. Since I'm unable to add comment yet, I'll put it as an answer.

Next time add a code sample with your question. It is hard to answer to questions like that.

`var df = FirstDataFrame
val dfprocessed = ProcessedDataFrame`

Assuming both DataFrame has same schema,

Try `df = df.union(dfprocessed)`

Hope this would help

Comment: I did this but for some reason it only returns the first dataframe. Another limitation is both the columns should have same number of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
val dbDf3 = dbDf1.union(dbDf3);
```

Use the above approach to union the dataframes. The care that needs to be taken here is, both dbDf1 and dbDf3 should have the exact same schema structure.

I am using this approach.

Comment: Thanks@BDA. For some reason union is not working. I have attached a picture above. Please see it.